# Reduzir consumo memória FireBird ao fechar Dataset

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

Tenho uma aplicação *Delphi XE7* que roda sobre um banco *FireBird 2.5*.
Quando abro uma `FDTable` com uns **10.000 registros** por exemplo, o consumo de memória do servidor do FireBird aumenta cerca de **1 MB**. Até aí tudo bem, faz parte.
Mas quando fecho a Table (`FDTable.Close;`) o consumo de memória não diminui... continua com o 1 MB que aumentou quando a table foi aberta.
O mesmo acontece com `FDQuerys` e também com outros bancos de dados.

Percebi que quando desconecto o `FDConnection` do banco, aí sim o consumo volta ao normal. Mas no momento não consigo fazer isso no meu sistema, ao menos não a curto prazo.

Tem algum jeito de quando um dataset ser fechado, reduzir proporcionalmente o consumo do SGDB no servidor?

Comment: nunca percebi isso... mais o que você já tentou?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trabalho com Firebird a muito tempo, o problema mesmo pode ser transações abertas.

Aqui não costumamos utilizar o `FDTable`, utilizamos um componente próprio, mas é a mesma coisa.

Vou dar um exemplo com o próprio `TDataSet`, que é a base de tudo.

```
var
  vDataSet_Teste : TDataSet;
begin
  vDataSet_Teste := ResultSQL('SELECT ALGUMA_COISA FROM ALGUM_LUGAR');

  while not vDataSet_Teste.Eof do
  begin
    Self.Caption := vDataSet_Teste.FieldByName('ALGUMA_COISA').AsString;
    vDataSet_Teste.Next;
  end;

  vDataSet_Teste.Close;
end;
```

Para este exemplo, considere que `ResultSQL` me devolve um dataset de dados.

`vDataSet_Teste.Close;` fecha apenas a possibilidade de ler os dados, mas não os remove da memória, pois, neste cenário o `ResultSQL` abriu uma transação, consultou os dados e me entregou para apreciação. Dessa forma ainda temos uma transação aberta, pois todo `DataSet` no Delphi é passado como memória, no caso, o dataset que foi carregado pela `ResultSQL` ainda existe e possui uma transação com o Servidor.

A forma que encontramos 100% eficaz foi utilizar um conjunto de comando para o dataset. Sendo ele uma `TQuery` ou um `TDataSet`:

```
vDataSet_Teste.Close;
vDataSet_Teste.Free;
```

Vale lembrar que nesse formato, não utilizamos componentes visuais.

Answer (score -2):

Tem uma rotina para reduzir a memória que colocada dentro de um timer ou após o seu processo:

```
    procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        if (((GetTickCount - LastTick) / 1000) > 120) or
             (Self.WindowState = wsMinimized) then
        begin
            //Memo1.Lines.Add(FormatFloat('Memory used: ,.# K', CurrentMemoryUsage / 1024));
            TrimAppMemorySize;
            //Memo1.Lines.Add('Reduz memória');
            //Memo1.Lines.Add(FormatFloat('Memory used: ,.# K', CurrentMemoryUsage / 1024));
        end;
    end;
```

A rotina para liberar a memória:

```
    procedure TrimAppMemorySize;
    var
        MainHandle : THandle;
    begin
        try
            MainHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, GetCurrentProcessID) ;
            SetProcessWorkingSetSize(MainHandle, $FFFFFFFF, $FFFFFFFF) ;
            CloseHandle(MainHandle) ;
        except
        end;
        Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
```

Para verificar a memória:

```
    function CurrentMemoryUsage: Cardinal;
    var
        pmc: TProcessMemoryCounters;
    begin
        pmc.cb := SizeOf(pmc) ;
        if GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess, @pmc, SizeOf(pmc)) then
            Result := pmc.WorkingSetSize
        else
            RaiseLastOSError;
    end;
```

Comment: `SetProcessWorkingSetSize(MainHandle, $FFFFFFFF, $FFFFFFFF) ;` este procedimento é fantasioso. Alimente uma `TClientDataSet` com 10 mb de dados, pode ser apenas isto, depois rode este processo, "vai limpar memória", depois percorra o mesmo `TClientDataSet` e veja o que acontece com a memória.

Comment: Uso o processo a anos e fiz teste de dias com aplicativos se subiam a memória e resolveu, se ainda não testou, ou não fez o processo completo, não vote sem ter certeza.

Comment: Existe um grande engano na utilização destes comandos e como se popularizou estes códigos no Brasil ... mas este código esta penas jogando o que não esta sendo utilizado no momento na memória para memória swap. Resumindo, você esta apenas jogando tudo para disco e assim que precisar acessar esta memória o windows vai jogar tudo de volta para a memória e aumentando o I/O de disco e deixando sua aplicação mais lenta. Não existe milagre para redução de memória, apenas boas práticas de codificação.

Comment: @Confundir foi exatamente o que expliquei a ele no comentário acima, e é tão fantasioso que leva o sujeito a crer que é milagroso! Expliquei um teste simples e pelo visto apenas sabe executar código, e como você disse: `apenas boas práticas de codificação.` resolve este tipo de problema!

Comment: Creio que você nunca criaram objetos em tempo de execução.....mesmo destruindo o consumo de memória em poucas horas podem ficar gigante.... só o código acima que resolveu o meu problema..... se não acredita ou não usa... não faça pouco caso de quem usa e funciona.... dar negativo...por dar... não faz sentido

Comment: Velho... comigo esse código funcionou só que não uso ele com as `TdataSet`, simplesmente `FdTable.close` já resolve meu problema.
no caso do @WellingtonTellesCunha deve funcionar para ocaso dele e para outros não seja a melhor solução.